# Android Emulator - invalid command-line parameter:

Tags: android-emulator

When I try to launch my [Android Virtual Device](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/index.html), I get the following error.

> Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools/emulator-arm.exe.
>   Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
>   Please use -help for more information.

I have been using the emulator for months, and I just downloaded new updates from SDK/AVD Manager.

Comment: Please refer to this post for a solution.  It did not come up in the search but it did correct my problem.  The space in the path name (PROGRAM FILES) seems to be causing the problem.  I took the the renaming suggestion to change the path name to PROGRA~1 and my problem was resolved.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603194/starting-android-emulator-in-sdk-tools-revision-12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer to the Stack Overflow post *[Starting the Android emulator in SDK tools, revision 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603194/starting-android-emulator-in-sdk-tools-revision-12)* for a solution. It did not come up in the search, but it did correct my problem. The space in the path name (PROGRAM FILES) seems to be causing the problem. I took the renaming suggestion to change the path name to `PROGRA~1`, and my problem was resolved.

Comment: Additional note: If you have "Program Files (x86)" folder, then it should be PROGRA~2.

Answer (score 9):

This problem is caused by blank spaces in the path you setup in the Android SDK. The solution is that you should move the folder of the Android SDK to a place without spaces, in your case:

```
E:\andriod-sdk-windows
```

or

```
D:\abc\xyz\android-sdk-windows
```

Comment: Thank you Hung Tran.  I changed the path name to remove the space by using PROGRA~1 instead of PROGRAM FILES as suggested in another link and it works now.

Comment: How does that work when you use visual studio?? with monotouch?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like someone already reported this problem, [Issue 18317: Emulator in R12 doesn't properly invoke emulator-arm.exe if the install path as a space in it](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18317&q=invalid%20command-line&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

> > ... to summarize:
>
> - Yes, there will be a fix. We're working on it.
> - The primary workaround is install in a path with no spaces, e.g. c:\android.
> - If that's not a choice, the second workaround right now is to use the "short path" Windows notation, e.g. "C:\PROGRA~1" either on
>     command lines or in the Eclipse preferences. Remember that the number might
>     change depending on your directories; you can use "dir /X c:\" in
>     cmd.exe to see the exact short path for a given directory.

We'll have to wait for their fix but in the meantime we can just remove the spaces in the Android installation directory.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse go to Windows -> Preferences -> Android and in your SDK location replace 
C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows with C:\PROGRA~1\android-sdk-windows

Comment: This post has already been answered about a month ago by myself and several other contributors.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the emulator only without eclipse you'll need to create a .bat file with the SDK short path:

for 32 bits machines:
C:\PROGRA~1\Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe

for 64 bits machines:
C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe