# Android emulator-arm.exe failed to launch a virtual device

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to run emulator-arm.exe, but I get this error. How do I fix this?

```
invalid command-line parameter: Files\tools/emulator-arm.exe.
Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
please use -help for more information.
```

Comment: If you already posted the question, then that is your question. Please do not post the same question multiple times.

Comment: Hum... Welcome to StackOverflow, pradeepa.
To improve the chances of getting effective help, you need to `IMPROVE YOUR QUESTION` !  The title is mostly uninformative, the body of question makes reference to a "last post" without pointing to it or copying excerpts from it, and on the whole the question doesn't provide any context other than a cut+paste of the error message!
Maybe you can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for ideas on how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 1):

sdk path can't contain spaces.May be you are putting your sdk somewhere like c:/windows/program files/...Lokk program files contains spaces.So remove spaces from your sdk path and try.Hopefully it will help

Answer (score 1):

The error message you've received is one symptom of this issue:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18317

To workaround that issue, which appears will be fixed in r13, you could either install the SDK in a location where the path doesn't have spaces, or keep the current location and supply the SDK location using the DOS 8.3 "short name"  path. The article above even has comments describing how to find that short path if you don't know how already.

Detailed StackOverflow answers for similar questions are here:

- [Starting the Android emulator in SDK tools, revision 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603194/starting-the-android-emulator-in-sdk-tools-revision-12)
- [Android Emulator - invalid command-line parameter:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629273/android-emulator-invalid-command-line-parameter)

I'd recommend providing details on OS, tools version, Eclipse version, etc. with your question, though, so people have fewer unknowns when answering. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found that in my case my antivirus deleted my emulator-arm.exe and emulator-x86.exe files. So i installed another antivirus and after that all was working!