# Is android application not running on Virtual Box?

Tags: java, android, windows-xp, virtualbox

I'm getting the following error while running the android application. Currently i'm using Windows XP and installed through Virtual Box.

```
invalid command-line parameter: Files\Android\android-sdk\tools/emulator-arm.exe.
Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
please use -help for more information
```

But that same application will running on normal Windows XP Pc. Is there any issue on Windows XP with Virtual Box? or Is there any other issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a bug with the emulator in the v12 release that does not play well with paths with spaces (that's why you see only `Files` instead of `c:\Program Files`). That's also why it works in your previous installation (pre-12) and not in the new one. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603194/starting-android-emulator-in-sdk-tools-revision-12).

Comment: Dmon: So what we do for this? Is there any other way?

Comment: I edited my solution and added a link to another one that lists possible solutions.