# Android project run error

Tags: android, android-emulator

Whenever I run the project an error is displayed. It says:

```
[2011-07-18 13:36:34 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: Files\android-sdk\tools/emulator-arm.exe.
[2011-07-18 13:36:34 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2011-07-18 13:36:34 - Emulator] please use -help for more information
```

I am not getting what's wrong.

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706490/is-android-application-not-running-on-virtual-box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced same issue. There is a bug with Android v12. See this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603194/starting-android-emulator-in-sdk-tools-revision-12) for your solution. And I followed **Carl S** answer. Now its working fine.