# Error Android Virtual Device with eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to crate New Android Virtual Device with eclipse but i had error,
[2011-07-21 15:12:22 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: and.
[2011-07-21 15:12:22 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2011-07-21 15:12:22 - Emulator] please use -help for more information

can any one help me?

Comment: You successfully created and AVD using eclipse, or that happens during creation?  How are you launching the AVD if the creation went ok?

Answer (score 1):

I had that one and for me it was a problem with the 'R12', it doesn't accept spaces in the install directory (of the Android SDK).

Instead of uninstall/reinstall, I changed in Eclipse from c:/program files/... to c:/Program~/... and it worked.

I didn't invent it, I found it here :
[Starting the Android emulator in SDK tools, revision 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603194/starting-android-emulator-in-sdk-tools-revision-12)

Answer (score 0):

```
SDK Path can't contain any spaces
```

Make sure your sdk path contains no spaces.May be you are changing the path of the android sdk folder.The path can't contain spaces.Like if you keep it in Program Files/android-sdk-windows it will create problem because Program Files has a space on the path