# Not able to launch android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I run my hello world application, the android emulator fails to launch.Even when i am creating a new emulator it fails to launch giving me the following error.

```
[2011-08-09 17:03:10 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: Files\Android\android-sdk\tools/emulator-arm.exe.
[2011-08-09 17:03:10 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2011-08-09 17:03:10 - Emulator] please use -help for more information
```

Comment: Your question already answered [here][1]

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603194/starting-the-android-emulator-in-sdk-tools-revision-12

Answer (score 8):

First of all you need to check are you in correct folder?

```
$...local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator -list-avds
```

If so it will show you list of emulators that you have in your Android studio you are on right track
 Last part for launching an emulator

```
local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator -avd Nexus_5X(name of your emulator you want to open)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you have specified your SDK in a file what has space, in its name For example: Android SDK You need to change it to something what hasn't got space in its name.

Hope it helps.

Or if you specified it in the Program Files use it:
Progra~1 instead of Program Files.

Comment: I would like to add this link. You'll need to change the android path in the preferences. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603194/starting-the-android-emulator-in-sdk-tools-revision-12

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying what AVD to launch. Please read the SDK docs in full, they will show you how to do this.

Tip: Launch the "android.exe" (I think, I use Linux where it's simply "android") app instead, create an AVD and launch it, all from the graphical interface.

Comment: I think it's android.bat, just to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

### The tricky part is finding name `@foo`

1. to find exact name of emulator run android command line `emulator -list-avds` aka `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -list-avds`
   2.it will show you emulator names but emulator names that you pass to command line

[image]

#### bonus: you probably will get PANIC error in that case you need to add ANDROID_PATH read more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49511666/6133329

Answer (score 0):

On windows don't install the Android SDK to a path with spaces in it like C:\Program Files\AndroidSDK. Instead install it to C:\AndroidSDK\ or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this It worked for me...

```
emulator @avd_name [ {-option [value]} … ]

Type command emulator @youremulatorname
```

[For more Check out this Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline)

Answer (score 0):

### For Windows

> Check whether you have an emulator on your PC.
> If it is there add the path below to the environment variable
> C:\Users%username%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
> and
> remove C:\Users\deepank\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools

: