# Unable to launch the android emulator from Eclipse 3.7.0

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Not able to launch android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995739/not-able-to-launch-android-emulator)
>   [Starting the Android emulator in SDK tools, revision 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603194/starting-the-android-emulator-in-sdk-tools-revision-12)

http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing I followed the instructions here for a windows 7 machine using a 64 bit operating system. It's a clean system install. I first installed the Android SDK and then installed Eclipse and then installed the ADT Plugin.

At first, simply nothing was happening. I'd click window-> android and it'd bring up the list of emulators I had made. I'd select one then click start and nothing. ADB.exe wasn't even in my systems resources. I made sure Kaspersky had added adb.exe to it's trusted list and tried again, still no dice.

I then saw an article saying I should move adb.exe from platform-tools to just tools so I tried that. That made it switch from doing nothing (and reporting nothing in the console or logcat) to where it is now. It says
invalid command-line parameter: Files.
Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
please use -help for more information

Any more theories on what I can try would be greatly appreciated.

For further clarification the foo message happened with platform of 2.3.3. or 3.2 selected. When trying platform 3.0 it went back to nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this trouble when my SDK was installed in 'Program Files'.

The invalid command line parameter was the space in the program files part of the argument. I guess Android coming from a Linux world means that whitespace is it's enemy! Despite this being the default install location.

I moved the whole SDK (emulator included) to the root 'C:\' drive. It then started working a treat.

Comment: This fixed the issue and allowed me to launch straight from eclipse. Thanks for the help. In the future I'll remember billion dollar corporations make mistakes to. :)

Comment: I think it's the M$ Linux war... I have a friend who has been using Windows for years and still panics when you send him a file with a space in the name and not an underscore!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem which was quite annoying me until I found a "fix" (well it does not solve the problem at its roots but helps a lot anyway):
Simple create a batch file with the following content:

> CD "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools"  
>   adb  kill-server && adb start-server

Of course you have to adjust the correct android platform-tools path.

So whenever a running emulator is not recognized by Eclipse or DDMS simply run this batch.

Comment: while I did not select this as the best answer, it is also a correct answer for those of you not wanting to try the solution I selected. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is bug on the windows version.

Open a command line prompt in the /tools/ folder (which you can find in the sdk folder) then run the **emulator-arm.exe -avd nameOfYourVirtualDeviceHere**

(btw this will not fix the real issue but allows you to continue to work)

Comment: while I did not select this as the best answer, it is also a correct answer for those of you not wanting to try the solution I selected. Thanks for your help.