# Setting up android simulator on Eclipse - error starting the simulator

Tags: android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Not able to launch android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995739/not-able-to-launch-android-emulator)

I just went through a smooth installation of android, and it seems to be working with my Eclipse.  But when I opened the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" and pressed new to launch the new simulator, the launch screen gave me this error:

"invalid command-line parameter: Files.
Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
please use -help for more information"

Any idea why that might occur?

Comment: Actually it's called "emulator", not "simulator".

Comment: I'm disappointed this question was closed.  It is a much better worded question, and the answers are much higher quality than the referenced question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows-->Preferences-->Android

set the SDK Location like this C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk

the problem is the character space on your path

Comment: Actually, how easy is it to just move my installation right to the c: ?

Comment: As easy as copy and pasting...I did that after running into an issue with spaces in the directory line.

Comment: Check if your installation is "Program Files" and than put C:\PROGRA~1\Android\android-sdk in SDK Location, instead if your installation is "Program Files (x86)" put C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk in SDK Location.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because you have spaces in your path.

Try this if you installed on windows in program files:

Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Android -> SDK Location: `C:\PROGRA~2\Android\android-sdk`