# Android emulators not starting

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Not able to launch android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995739/not-able-to-launch-android-emulator)

After downloading Eclipse indigo, and updating the Android SDK, android Emulators are not starting, the progress bar completes fully but i get the following error and nothing happens:

```
invalid command-line parameter: Files\Android\android-sdk\tools/emulator-arm.exe.
Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
please use -help for more information
```

Also when i start eclipse, i get the error that Android i get the error that Location of Android SDK has not been set up in Preferences, but in preferences i have set up the location, which is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the path of the SDK your path is Program Files\Android\android-sdk tools/. put SDK directly in the drive ie. d:\Android\android-sdk-tools\

note: also remove spaces from the path by renaming the folder name

Answer (score 1):

check your sdk path. Make sure the path should not have an empty space like ....`/my  Sdk/`sdk-windos/