# Android Emulator Error Message: "PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPUS."

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to run an Android Emulator by using AVD Manager.
I have a Macbook Pro Retina. Installed the Haxm driver direct from intel page.

No emulator is working. All get the same "error" message.

Running Command (This error was when i used Homebrew for installing Android-sdk and Android-platform-tools | anyone who get the same problem should remove this or look where the conflict is)

```
export ANDROID_EMULATOR_DEBUG=1 test20

emulator:Found AVD name 'test20'
emulator:Found AVD target architecture: x86
emulator:Looking for emulator-x86 to emulate 'x86' CPU
emulator:Probing program: ./emulator-x86
emulator:Probing path for: emulator-x86
emulator:Found target-specific emulator binary: /usr/local/bin/emulator-x86
emulator:Probing for: /usr/local/bin/libOpenglRender.dylib
emulator:Probing for: /usr/local/bin/lib/libOpenglRender.dylib
emulator:Probing for: /usr/local/lib/libOpenglRender.dylib
emulator:Probing for: /usr/local/bin/lib64OpenglRender.dylib
emulator:Probing for: /usr/local/bin/lib/lib64OpenglRender.dylib
emulator:Probing for: /usr/local/lib/lib64OpenglRender.dylib
emulator:Could not find OpenGLES emulation host libraries!
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!

emulator -avd test21
emulator:Found AVD name 'test21'
emulator:Found AVD target architecture: x86_64
emulator:Looking for emulator backend for x86_64 CPU
emulator:Probing program: ./emulator-x86_64
emulator:Probing path for: emulator-x86_64
emulator:Looking for emulator-x86 to emulate 'x86_64' CPU
emulator:Probing program: ./emulator-x86
emulator:Probing path for: emulator-x86
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86_64' CPUS.
```

After I fixed the problem with Homebrew:

I tried a bit around and found this:

```
emulator64-x86 -avd test20
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library: dlopen(lib64OpenglRender.dylib, 1): image not found
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
qemu: could not load PC BIOS 'bios.bin'
```

For all who has the same problem,  maybe these steps help:

Run your Emulator in Debug mode:

```
export ANDROID_EMULATOR_DEBUG=1 emulatorName
```

If there is a path that look strange check for other installations like Homebrew and remove the conflict (uninstall one)

When the library is missing you need to export the variable:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib
```

And when error "qemu: could not load PC BIOS 'bios.bin'" appears, one fix is to run the emulator with the full path:

```
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86 -avd test20
In your case it is maybe a other path.
```

Comment: in my case this error came up because the SDK manager didn't install the 32 bit binaries (emulator-arm and emulator-x86), but the emulator program still looked for them by default. Deleting and re-installing the sdk tools didn't add the 32 binaries for me.  I can launch the emulator by running emulator64-arm -avd 'avdname' from Terminal, but I still can't get Android Studio's AVD manager to realize it needs to look for the 64 bit binary. Eclipse's AVD manager seems to be fine

Comment: None of the PATH fixes worked for me, whether I was in `emulator` or `tools` - I had to manually specify the `-kernel` argument per this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/52161215/3700490

Comment: I've just left an actual solution, which solves the problem instead of working around it.

Comment: Based off several of these answers, to save the hard work, I just did an uninstall and reinstall of the HAXM via SDK manager and the problem went away.

Answer (score 552, accepted):

If you are using macOS, add both Android SDK `emulator` and `tools` directories to the path:

**Step 1:** In my case the order was important, first `emulator` and then `tools`.

```
export ANDROID_SDK=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/emulator:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$PATH
```

**Step 2:** Reload you `.bash_profile` Or `.bashrc` depending on OS

**Step 3:** Get list of emulators available:
`$emulator -list-avds`

**Step 4:** Launch emulator from the command line and Replace `avd` with the name of your emulator `$emulator @avd`

Don't forget to add the `@` symbol.

This was tested with macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 and Android Studio 3.1.2.

Comment: This is the right answer as the $ANDROID_SDK/tools/emulator needs access to the types of emulator architecture found in the $ANDROID_SDK/emulator/ folder.

Comment: I wrote about this change [here](https://www.stkent.com/2017/08/10/update-your-path-for-the-new-android-emulator-location.html) if you're interested in some context :)

Comment: This same answer applies to Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver.

Comment: Nice.  This also fixed an error: "Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio"

Comment: What if you're using Windows?

Comment: Maybe you could add `ANDROID_SDK` and modify `PATH` via environment variables, using System Properties dialog box.

Comment: The issue was persisting for me even after doing `source ~/.bash_profile` so I had to relaunch the terminal. The issue was resolved after this. If you get "../tools/emulator" when you run `which emulator`, the path has not been set properly. So just relaunch your terminal.

Comment: not working for me !!!

Comment: on linux use:
```
export ANDROID_SDK=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/emulator:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$PATH
```
(note no Library dir and cap S)
If this doesn't work make sure you aren't running virtualbox!

Answer (score 232):

I had this issue after upgrading Android Studio to 3.2 and even upgrade some SDK-Packages.

The cause was that the path to emulator had changed, so **don't use**

```
...../Android/Sdk/tools/emulator
```

**but** instead

```
..../Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator
```

Comment: I am using Android Studio 3.4.2 and this solution worked for me too.

Comment: this works for me. do you know how can I change the main emulator shortcut (softlink) to the correct one?

Comment: This one worked for me (without changing paths and things that may cause another issue). Thanks!

Comment: On Windows 10, Android Studio 2022.1 this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 68):

The following work-around to start emulator-x86 worked for me:

```
cd $SDK/tools; 
ln -s emulator64-x86 emulator-x86
```

Or on Windows open Command Prompt (Admin)

```
cd %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\tools
mklink emulator64-x86.exe emulator-x86.exe
```

And now the emulator will start from the SDK manager.

## **IMPORTANT Note**:

> Emulators is located in `emulators` folder in more recent versions.
> (thanks to `rmtheis` for info)

Comment: how can i fix it in windows?

Comment: Actually this solved my problem: `ln -s emulator64-x86 emulator-x86_64`

Comment: The emulators have been moved out of `tools` and into the `emulator` directory.

Comment: As @rmtheis says, more than creating a symbolic link and trying to cheat the system, you should check and add the correct executable in the path. Run `which emulator` to check which one is actually being picked.  `/Users/{$USER_NAME}/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator` is the right executable to be used.

Comment: @Sameer - Not sure your suggestion fixes the same issue my solution did.  My solution effectively fixes a bug in the SDK.  IIRC, the SDK install did already configure the path, but unfortunately missed some critical binaries on 64 bit systems.  Using `which` would not have found the correct binary since it was not in the path in the first place.

I considered a path based solution, but felt the symlink solution is more likely to survive an upgrade and be self contained.

Also, sounds like the SDK creators have moved things around since 2015, not sure my solution is relevant anymore.

Comment: @Tongfa I'm definitely hinting at the relevancy of your solution, more than its accuracy. With the way, the binaries have been moved around, one should definitely consider choosing the binaries in the `emulator` folder over the ones in the `tools` folder. You are right when you say that `which` wouldn't find the binary since it wasn't even in the path to begin with. In this case, any one who's viewing this problem, should use `which` as a confirmatory tool, and should make appropriate changes to give precedence to the binaries from the `emulator` folder.

Comment: For CLI devs, change all `/Users/amama/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator @PIXEL_2_XL` to `/Users/amama/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator @PIXEL_2_XL`

Comment: @RayFoss' solution worked for me with Android 28 -- running `emulator/emulator.exe` instead of `tools/emulator`.

Comment: It worked. Actually emulators moved from `tools` folder to `emulator` folder

Answer (score 64):

Navigate to the emulator folder located within `Android SDK folder` / `emulator`

`cd ${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator`

Then type these command to open emulator without android studio:

```
$ ./emulator -list-avds
$ ./emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_28_x86
```

`Nexus_5X_API_28_x86` is My AVD you need to give your AVD name

Answer (score 39):

For Windows 10, 5.29.18 :

Using command promt I just got in the emulator directory:

```
cd C:\Android\sdk\emulator
```

and then typed  the command:

```
emulator -avd Nexus_S_API_27
```

`Nexus_S_API_27` is the name of my custom emulator.

Othewize it will abuse :

```
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.
```

Comment: In my case it throwed `PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.` on valid AVD path. As described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51627009/2914140, newer versions of emulators use `emulator/emulator` path, while I started from `tools/emulator`.

Answer (score 27):

In my case by doing `which emulator` it returned `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator`
but it should be `$ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator`

So I just added `$ANDROID_HOME/emulator` before `$ANDROID_HOME/tools` in the PATH variable and it works fine now

Comment: This was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

On Mac after installing Android Studio IDE `android-studio-ide-173.4907809-mac.dmg` and using studio SDK Manager to install SDK Tools

[image]

Add to your PATH using `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` and make sure you have `$ANDROID_HOME/emulator` in your `$PATH` before `$ANDROID_HOME/tools` like so:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

alias androidemulator='emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_28_x86'
```

Comment: This led me to a simple solution on Windows 10 and Android Studio. For some unknown reason, emulator was not installed and Android Emulator was not checked.(though I used it last week, perhaps a botched update of Android Studio). Check it, click Apply button, install emulator, then all was good.

Answer (score 18):

In my Case this works like a charm:

1. Open **Terminal**
2. Type: `open ~/.bash_profile`
3. Add the following lines:

   ```
   export ANDROID_SDK=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
   export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/emulator:$PATH
   export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$PATH
   export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/tools/bin:$PATH
   export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$PATH
   export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_SDK 
   export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=$HOME/.android/and
   alias emulator='$ANDROID_SDK/emulator/emulator'
   ```
4. Save (hit *Command+S*). You may close the window or not.
5. Back to Terminal, type: `source ~/.bash_profile`
6. Show the installed emulators: `emulator -list-avds`, something like:

   ```
   Pixel_2_API_29
   Pixel_3a_API_29
   Pixel_C_API_29
   ```
7. Last, run the emulator: `emulator @Pixel_2_API_29`

Comment: Great answer. Looks like you cover all the basis for setting up a new machine's PATH for Android Studio.

Answer (score 13):

There are two named `emulator` binary file. which located under `$SDK/tools/emulator` another under `$SDK/emulator/`

- please make sure you have the right emulator configure(need add `$SDK/emulator` to your env PATH

I have write a script to help me to invoke the avd list

```
    #!/bin/bash -e


    echo "--- $# $(PWD)"
    HOME_CURRENT=$(PWD)
    HOME_EMULATOR=/Users/pcao/Library/Android/sdk/emulator

    if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "ERROR pls try avd 23 or avd 28 " 
    fi

    if [ "$1" = "23" ]
    then
        echo "enter 23"
        cd $HOME_EMULATOR
        ./emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_23_Android6_ &
        cd $HOME_CURRENT
    fi

    if [ "$1" = "28" ]
    then
        echo "enter 28"
        cd $HOME_EMULATOR
        ./emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_28_GooglePlay_ &
        cd $HOME_CURRENT
    fi
```

Comment: In my case it was because $ANDROID_SDK/tools was in path before $ANDROID_SDK/emulator.

Answer (score 13):

**Tested on macOS Mojave 10.14.5.**

**Reason and Solution:**

we use **`sdk/tools/emulator/emulator`**, we should use **`sdk/emulator`**.

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:~ zgong$ emulator -avd Pixel_3_XL_API_Q_x86
PANIC: Unknown AVD name [Pixel_3_XL_API_Q_x86], use -list-avds to see valid list.
HOME is defined but there is no file Pixel_3_XL_API_Q_x86.ini in $HOME/.android/avd
(Note: Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/avd, and $HOME/.android/avd)
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:~ zgong$ emulator -avd Pixel_3_XL_API_Q
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.
```

We could check the emulator location:

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:~ zgong$ which emulator
/Users/zgong/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator
```

> I did a bunch of googling and while most of the answers were about
> setting the paths correctly in terminal, it turns out it was actually
> to do with a shift in a recent version of the SDK, where the emulator
> app is located in /emulator instead of /tools. Leaving this here in
> case anyway runs into the same problem.

**We need to use as below:**

`{sdk location}/emulator -avd {avd name}`

Here is the real output:

```
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:~ zgong$ /Users/zgong/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_3_XL_API_Q
pc_memory_init: above 4g size: 40000000
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version, skipping check (current version '29.2.1-5889189')
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error
WebSocketServer listening on port 55850
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/resources. Trying parent directory...
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/resources. Trying parent directory...
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64. Trying application directory...
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64. Trying application directory...
Installed Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/translations/qtwebengine_locales. Trying application directory...
Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /Users/zgong/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/libexec/qtwebengine_locales. Trying fallback directory... Translations MAY NOT not be correct.
Installed Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/translations/qtwebengine_locales. Trying application directory...
Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /Users/zgong/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/libexec/qtwebengine_locales. Trying fallback directory... Translations MAY NOT not be correct.
Path override failed for key ui::DIR_LOCALES and path '/Users/zgong/.QtWebEngineProcess'
Path override failed for key ui::DIR_LOCALES and path '/Users/zgong/.QtWebEngineProcess'
Qt WebEngine resources not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/resources. Trying parent directory...
Qt WebEngine resources not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64. Trying application directory...
Qt WebEngine resources not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/resources. Trying parent directory...
Qt WebEngine resources not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64. Trying application directory...
[0403/154905.171893:WARNING:resource_bundle_qt.cpp(116)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale
[0403/154905.171871:WARNING:resource_bundle_qt.cpp(116)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/resources. Trying parent directory...
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64. Trying application directory...
Installed Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/translations/qtwebengine_locales. Trying application directory...
Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /Users/zgong/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/libexec/qtwebengine_locales. Trying fallback directory... Translations MAY NOT not be correct.
Path override failed for key ui::DIR_LOCALES and path '/Users/zgong/.QtWebEngineProcess'
Qt WebEngine resources not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64/resources. Trying parent directory...
Qt WebEngine resources not found at /Users/joshuaduong/qt-build-5.12.1/install-darwin-x86_64. Trying application directory...
[0403/154907.393116:WARNING:resource_bundle_qt.cpp(116)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale
```

Reference:
https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/a978kx/mac_can_run_emulator_fine_through_android_studio/

Comment: `.../sdk/emulator` is a directory in my installation. The executable is `.../sdk/emulator/emulator`

Answer (score 8):

Simply follow the below steps specific to mac:

1. go to:
   `/Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk/emulator`
2. `./emulator -list-avds`
3. `./emulator @avdName`

Answer (score 5):

ON WINDOWS - updating the system path worked for me. Create an environment variable for the location of your sdk called `ANDROID_SDK` then add these to your path, in this order:

```
%ANDROID_SDK%\emulator
%ANDROID_SDK%\platform-tools
%ANDROID_SDK%\tools
%ANDROID_SDK%\tools\bin
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I needed to install Android Emulator from Sdk manager and it get fixed

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can also try what is suggested here: https://www.stkent.com/2017/08/10/update-your-path-for-the-new-android-emulator-location.html

For short, run the emulator from the `sdk/emulator` folder

Answer (score 4):

Hit below command. It work for me. Android has changed the emulator directory from **/tools** to **sdk/emulator**

```
/Users/yourusername/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_API_27
```

Answer (score 3):

Latest Android Studio path has changed.

Use below path to locate emulator

```
cd /Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/emulator
```

And then run this command

```
./emulator -avd Pixel_2_XL_API_28
```

My emulator name is "Pixel 2 XL API 28"

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot start emulator-x86 directory, because it needs to have LD_LIBRARY_PATH setup specially to find the PC Bios and GPU emulation libraries (that's why 'emulator' exists, it modifies the path, then calls emulator-x86).

Did you update the first ouput ? It looks like 'emulator' is still finding ' /usr/local/bin/emulator-x86'

Comment: I don't now fixed it in my entry. I let it there if anyone else maybe have problems like this and see my problems, but I add a description to it :D

Answer (score 2):

Try the following work-around to start emulator-x86:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$SDK/tools/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$SDK/tools/emulator-x86 <your-other-options>
```

Where $SDK is the path to your SDK installation. That's in a nutshell what 'emulator' tries to do. You might want to start emulator64-x86 instead of emulator-x86 if the former exists though.

Comment: Thanks anyway! you moved me a lot steps forward :). I used the export with the library path and startet the emulator. Now he tells me ### emulator64-x86 -avd test20 |
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast girt mode |
qemu: could not load PC BIOS 'bios.bin' ### one file is still missing

Comment: Okay this get fixed if I run the emulator with the full path, why ever Oo? /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86 -avd test20 Maybe you know how to fix this :D?

Comment: The problem with "bios.bin" was solved here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/gwcLeOTfxD4/kW-qebk0C-wJ

Comment: The emulators have been moved from `tools` into `emulator`.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue on Windows7 64bit. The reason why it didn't was missing `emulator-x86.exe` file under sdk/tools. Fixed it by deleting Android SDK Tools using Android SDK Manager and installing it again. The file now exists and emulator works as expected.

Comment: After deleting Android SDK Tools - don't close sdk manager. Or you cannot install it again. Poor answer with out warnings.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this resolved my problem on windows 10 64 bit. I also kept my sdk manager opened as @Kiran suggested

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and never worked for me except until go to the emulator folder, I tried to export the emulator folder but not worked for me

```
cd $android_home/emulator and run emulator
```

, in the end, I write Elias for the command in .bashrc file

```
alias emulator="$ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator"
```

Comment: Instead of `cd`ing to the emulator directory, adding the `$ANDROID_HOME/emulator` to the PATH is sufficient

Comment: I tried to add the emulator folder to the path but not worked.

Comment: Please make sure you add it before $ANDROID_HOME/tools

Answer (score 1):

Avast Antivirus is sensing emulator-arm.exe as a thread and blocking from some reasons. When you add it exclusions in Virus Chest page with right-click -> "restore and add to exclusions" it's not solved in future runnings. To solve this permanently in Avast 2015 :

Settings ->

Active Protection ->

File System Shield ->

Customize ->

Exclusions then add thread as a exclusion . And then press ok.

Answer (score 1):

Delete both Android SDK Tools and Android SDK PLatform-tools; then download both packages again. Now, create a new emulator and start it; it will work. You might be able to run your old emulators.

Comment: Very important to install the emulator and then START IT from Android Studio so the emulator bootstraps android first

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on macOS:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:'$HOME'/Library/Android/sdk/emulator:'$HOME'/Library/Android/sdk/tools:'$HOME'/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

First, check the path you get with `which emulator` and if you get `/usr/local/share/android-sdk/tools/emulator` then remove or rename that emulator (it's an old one) and instead use `/usr/local/share/android-sdk/emulator/emulator` which is [the new path](https://www.stkent.com/2017/08/10/update-your-path-for-the-new-android-emulator-location.html).

If you're using Homebrew and installed with `brew cask install android-sdk android-studio` then you need to:

1. Verify your .bashrc or .zshrc that you have the correct paths set:

```
# Remove $HOME/Library/Android paths
# The new way is to use ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/usr/local/share/android-sdk"
# For good measure, add old paths to be backwards compatible with any scripts or 
whatnot. And to hopefully decrease confusion:
export ANDROID_HOME=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/ndk-bundle
```

2. Then restart your terminal shell, and check your paths are as you expect them:

   `set | grep ANDROID`
3. Finally, with correct paths set, you typically need to install the ndk and some tools:

   `sdkmanager "ndk-bundle" "cmake;3.10.2.4988404" "lldb;3.1"`

   and check the list for other pieces like this `sdkmanager --list`

I also closed Android Studio, removed the old Android/Sdk folder under my $HOME folder, and restarted Studio, and when it asked where my Sdk had gone, I pasted the Sdk path: `/usr/local/share/android-sdk`

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu users

If you are getting `PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.`
 this error

Try starting your emulator from the emulator folder in SDK, like above

```
usama@usama-Aspire-V5-471:~/Android/Sdk/emulator$ ./emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_29
```

Comment: I had removed the link and simply explained. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue stems from SDK changes, since `emulator` now has it's own directory.
I didn't notice (nor care) to run an outdated emulator, while it still worked ...
This is a stalled SDK migration. When running with the `-verbose` switch:

```
emulator -avd Nexus_6_API_R -verbose
```

One can see where it starts to panic:

```
emulator:try dir C:\Android\tools
emulator:Looking for emulator-x86 to emulate 'x86' CPU
emulator:Probing program: C:\Android\tools/emulator-x86.exe
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.
```

But there is no `emulator-x86.exe` available and the actual emulator resides in directory `emulator`. After uninstalling "SDK Tools" (while trying to reinstall them), that one entry unexpectedly vanished from the list, leaving an empty `tools` directory, which may be deleted and removed from `PATH`.

Using `x86_64` emulation is not required nor suggested (as this will run the stalled version of the emulator). Adapting to the SDK path changes by uninstalling "SDK Tools" is rather "the answer". One probably could just replace `tools` with `emulator` on `PATH`, but this leaves clutter behind.

---

For comparison, the actual startup sequence of version `30.3.5.0` should look about like this:

```
emulator: Android emulator version 30.3.5.0 (build_id 7033400) (CL:N/A)
emulator: Found AVD name 'Nexus_6_API_R'
emulator: Found AVD target architecture: arm
emulator: argv[0]: 'emulator.exe'; program directory: 'C:\Android\emulator'
```

And if there may be follow up errors alike:

```
PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value
```

This means that the system image path inside the `*.ini` may be wrongful.
It helps to download the `x86` system image and then create a new emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Example that works for me on OSX / MacOS (replace name of device)

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator @Pixel_2_API_28 -no-snapshot -wipe-data
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a virtual device with the lowest possible Android version that was acceptable in my case worked for me. (Before that I'd tried several recent Android versions and had been getting the `Missing emulator engine program for 'x86_64' CPUS` error.)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was using the integrated terminal in VS Code. That showed me a different path setting (and so tools path instead of emulator path was shown in the first place). All you need is to change the global vscode settings by using the correct bash as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53971796/3437868

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue was caused by the default AVD using hardware accelerated GLES when setting is "auto". Had to edit the AVD and set it to "Software - GLES 2.0"

[image: settings]

Answer (score -1):

This message means the 'emulator-x86' or 'emulator64-x86' program is missing from $SDK/tools/, or cannot be found for some reason.

First of all, are you sure you have a valid download / install of the SDK?

Comment: I thought I have a valid download. Downloaded it twice but I could try again.

Comment: and i tried again... same message. I removed all installed from sdk Manager, installed them back, removed all avd images and .... But it still does not work :/ At my Windows 7 PC I just need 5min and it run but something is wrong at my Mac :/

Comment: Can you start manually from the command-line, i.e.:

  $SDK/tools/emulator @<avd-name>

If this doesn't work, can you try defining ANDROID_EMULATOR_DEBUG to 1, as in:

  export ANDROID_EMULATOR_DEBUG=1
  $SDK/tools/emulator @<avd-name> -verbose

This should print information about what the program is trying to do (i.e. locating the engine binaries). Please let us know the output.

Comment: When i run emulator -avd test20
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!

Comment: The following is extremely strange:

    emulator:Found target-specific emulator binary: /usr/local/bin/emulator-x86

Where did you install your SDK exactly? Is there really a file named /usr/local/bin/emulator-x86 on your machine (and if so, where does it come from?)

Comment: Yes the file /usr/local/bin/emulator-x86 exists. My Android SDK is located here: /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk . But I don't know where the emulator-86 come from. I also installed phonegap via Home Brew, maybe from there?

Comment: It looks like HomeBrew installs its own version of the emulator that interacts badly with the version from the SDK. I recommend uninstalling phonegap to resolve the problem.

Comment: would explain why it worked some days ago, i will try.

Comment: I removed now with: brew unstinall android-platform-tools and brew uninstall android-sdk . The output from emulator if i run now in debug mode is: emulator:Found AVD name 'test20'
emulator:Found AVD target architecture: x86
emulator:Looking for emulator-x86 to emulate 'x86' CPU
emulator:Probing program: ./emulator-x86
emulator:Probing path for: emulator-x86
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPUS.    I will try now to reinstall the files via the sdk-manager from Android Studio

Comment: I add the Debug print to my post. It seems not to be fixed :/

Answer (score -3):

See if your .exe file is in your antivirus quarantine

Solutions:

1. Download the adt-bundle again from https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk.
2. Open the Zip File.
3. Copy the missing .exe Files From the Folder `\sdk\tools`.
4. Past the Copied Files in Your `Android\sdk\tools` Directory.