# PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86_64' CPUS

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Having a problem starting the android emulator from inside eclipse. 
I get the error : PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86_64' CPUS

[image]

I can start the emulator from the command line :

./emulator64-x86 @Nexus5_21

HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode

I am using the ADT bundled eclipse.

I tried to set export the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my profile ( found another article that suggested that )
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/lindkris/Documents/private/Android/android-sdk-macosx/tools/lib:/Users/lindkris/Documents/private/Android/android-sdk-macosx/tools/emulator64-x86

[image]

[image]

I also installed the Android Studio 0.8.14, and here I have the same problem... 
[image]

Comment: Check out your antivirus didn't put the emulator executable in quarantine.

Comment: Try some of the solutions offered in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483370/android-emulator-error-message-panic-missing-emulator-engine-program-for-x86)

Comment: Der Golem : If it was some permissions or quarantine I guess I could not start from command line...

Comment: ChrisS : I saw that post, but that didn't help me much. It seems like that was a problem with downloading the SDK from HomeBrew

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Emulator Error Message: "PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPUS."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483370/android-emulator-error-message-panic-missing-emulator-engine-program-for-x86)

Answer (score 1):

If you have Avast antivirus then try this its worked for me!

Open Avast Antivirus > Scan > Quarantine > Right Click on "emulator-arm.exe" > Restore