# PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPUS

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am trying to run my first Android "Hello World" program. But while doing that, Android studio gives an error. Below are all of the details.

IDE - Android Studio.

OS - OSX (Version - 10.9.5)

Command -

```
/Users/hiteshj/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none
```

Error -

```
0c4de9c3b43a:AndroidStudioProjects hiteshj$ /Users/hiteshj/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86 --verbose
emulator:Found AVD name 'Nexus_5_API_21_x86'
emulator:Found AVD target architecture: x86
emulator:Looking for emulator-x86 to emulate 'x86' CPU
emulator:Probing program: /Users/hiteshj/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator-x86
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPUS.
```

But when I run below command through shell, then it opens Emulator successfully.

```
/Users/hiteshj/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86 -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none
```

Here is the logs :-

```
0c4de9c3b43a:tools hiteshj$ ./emulator64-x86 -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86 -verbose
emulator: found SDK root at /Users/hiteshj/Library/Android/sdk
emulator: Android virtual device file at: /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21_x86.ini
emulator: virtual device content at /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 21
emulator: Read property file at /Users/hiteshj/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86//build.prop
emulator: No boot.prop property file found.
emulator: found skin 'nexus_5' in directory: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/device-art-resources
emulator: autoconfig: -skin nexus_5
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/device-art-resources
emulator: keyset loaded from: /Users/hiteshj/.android/default.keyset
emulator: trying to load skin file '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/device-art-resources/nexus_5/layout'
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /Users/hiteshj/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86//kernel-qemu
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires legacy device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /Users/hiteshj/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: /Users/hiteshj/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86//system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 1536MB

emulator: CPU Acceleration: working
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: HAX (version 2) is installed and usable.
emulator: Target arch = 'x86'
emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu qemu32
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = x86
  hw.cpu.model = qemu32
  hw.ramSize = 1536
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = no
  hw.trackBall = no
  hw.keyboard = no
  hw.keyboard.lid = no
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = no
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = yes
  hw.sdCard.path = /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd/sdcard.img
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 1080
  hw.lcd.height = 1920
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 480
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = yes
  hw.initialOrientation = portrait
  hw.camera.back = emulated
  hw.camera.front = emulated
  vm.heapSize = 64
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  hw.useext4 = yes
  kernel.path = /Users/hiteshj/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86//kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.checkjni=1
  kernel.newDeviceNaming = no
  kernel.supportsYaffs2 = no
  disk.ramdisk.path = /Users/hiteshj/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86//ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = /Users/hiteshj/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86//system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 750m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 550m
  avd.name = Nexus_5_API_21_x86
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "./emulator64-x86"
emulator: argv[01] = "-enable-hax"
emulator: argv[02] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[03] = "/Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 ./emulator64-x86 -enable-hax -android-hw /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Using kernel serial device prefix: ttyS
emulator: Ramdisk image contains fstab.goldfish file
emulator: Found format of system partition: 'ext4'
emulator: Found format of userdata partition: 'ext4'
emulator: Found format of cache partition: 'ext4'
emulator: system partition format: ext4
emulator: Mapping 'system' partition image to /tmp/android-hiteshj/emulator-GMFbum
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0x2ee00000,file=/tmp/android-hiteshj/emulator-GMFbum,initfile=/Users/hiteshj/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86//system.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: userdata partition format: ext4
emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0x22600000,file=/Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd/userdata-qemu.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: cache partition format: ext4
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd/cache.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '64m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '480'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'both'
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=1 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.checkjni=1 ndns=1
emulator:     trying to find: /Users/hiteshj/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bios.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /Users/hiteshj/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/pc-bios/bios.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /Users/hiteshj/Library/Android/sdk/tools/vgabios-cirrus.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /Users/hiteshj/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/pc-bios/vgabios-cirrus.bin

emulator: autoconfig: -scale 0.27817
emulator: Forcing ro.adb.qemud to "0".
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: sent '0012host:emulator:5555' to ADB server
emulator: ping program: /Users/hiteshj/Library/Android/sdk/tools/./ddms
emulator: ping command: /Users/hiteshj/Library/Android/sdk/tools/./ddms ping emulator standalone "Intel Inc." "Intel HD Graphics 4000 OpenGL Engine" "2.1 INTEL-8.28.32"
```

In tools folder,

```
ls -1 emulator*

emulator
emulator64-arm
emulator64-mips
emulator64-x86
```

Please tell me why Android Studio is not able to open Emulator ?

I think that I have put all the information related to this issue. If I have forgetten any information, please ask. Thanks

Comment: Now that working Emulator also stuck. Please help  me.

Comment: Have you checked out [this answer][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483370/android-emulator-error-message-panic-missing-emulator-engine-program-for-x86

Comment: That time I installed genymotion package in android studio. That work for me. I will put my answer soon.