# Android Studio stuck starting the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am new to `Android` development. I am stuck while writing an Hello World program.

`Android Studio` got stuck at the time of opening emulator.

OS - MacBook Pro

It stuck after showing below statements,

```
Waiting for device.
/Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_19 -netspeed full -netdelay none
```

and, then it shows,

```
/Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_19 -netspeed full -netdelay none
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPUS.
```

Some logs(emulator verbose in debug mode) related to above problem,

log 1 :-

```
0c4de9c3b43a:~ hiteshj$ /Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_19 -netspeed full -netdelay none -verbose
emulator:Found AVD name 'Nexus_5_API_19'
emulator:Found AVD target architecture: x86
emulator:Looking for emulator-x86 to emulate 'x86' CPU
emulator:Probing program: /Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools/emulator-x86
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPUS.
0c4de9c3b43a:~ hiteshj$
```

log 2 :-

```
0c4de9c3b43a:~ hiteshj$ /Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools/emulator64-x86 -avd Nexus_5_API_19 -netspeed full -netdelay none -verbose
emulator: found SDK root at /Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx
emulator: Android virtual device file at: /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_19.ini
emulator: virtual device content at /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_19.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_19.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_19.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 19
emulator: Read property file at /Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/add-ons/addon-google_apis_x86-google-19/images/x86//build.prop
emulator: No boot.prop property file found.
emulator: found skin 'nexus_5' in directory: /Volumes/Android Studio 1.0.1/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/device-art-resources
emulator: autoconfig: -skin nexus_5
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /Volumes/Android Studio 1.0.1/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/device-art-resources
emulator: writing default keyset file to /Users/hiteshj/.android/default.keyset
emulator: trying to load skin file '/Volumes/Android Studio 1.0.1/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/device-art-resources/nexus_5/layout'
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/add-ons/addon-google_apis_x86-google-19/images/x86//kernel-qemu
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires legacy device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/add-ons/addon-google_apis_x86-google-19/images/x86//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: /Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/add-ons/addon-google_apis_x86-google-19/images/x86//system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_19.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_19.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_19.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 1536MB

emulator: CPU Acceleration: working
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: HAX (version 2) is installed and usable.
emulator: Target arch = 'x86'
emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu qemu32
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = x86
  hw.cpu.model = qemu32
  hw.ramSize = 1536
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = no
  hw.trackBall = no
  hw.keyboard = yes
  hw.keyboard.lid = no
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = no
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = yes
  hw.sdCard.path = /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_19.avd/sdcard.img
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_19.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 1080
  hw.lcd.height = 1920
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 480
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = yes
  hw.initialOrientation = portrait
  hw.camera.back = none
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 64
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  hw.useext4 = yes
  kernel.path = /Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/add-ons/addon-google_apis_x86-google-19/images/x86//kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.checkjni=1
  kernel.newDeviceNaming = no
  kernel.supportsYaffs2 = yes

  disk.systemPartition.initPath = /Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/add-ons/addon-google_apis_x86-google-19/images/x86//system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 550m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_19.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.initPath = /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_19.avd/userdata.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 550m
  avd.name = Nexus_5_API_19
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "/Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools/emulator64-x86"
emulator: argv[01] = "-netspeed"
emulator: argv[02] = "full"
emulator: argv[03] = "-netdelay"
emulator: argv[04] = "none"
emulator: argv[05] = "-enable-hax"
emulator: argv[06] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[07] = "/Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_19.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 /Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools/emulator64-x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none -enable-hax -android-hw /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_19.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Using kernel serial device prefix: ttyS
emulator: Ramdisk image contains fstab.goldfish file
emulator: Found format of system partition: 'ext4'
emulator: Found format of userdata partition: 'ext4'
emulator: Found format of cache partition: 'ext4'
emulator: system partition format: ext4
emulator: Mapping 'system' partition image to /tmp/android-hiteshj/emulator-Fy3cVN
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0x22600000,file=/tmp/android-hiteshj/emulator-Fy3cVN,initfile=/Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/add-ons/addon-google_apis_x86-google-19/images/x86//system.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: userdata partition format: ext4
emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0x22600000,file=/Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_19.avd/userdata-qemu.img,initfile=/Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_19.avd/userdata.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: cache partition format: ext4
emulator: Creating empty cache partition image at: /Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_19.avd/cache.img
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/Users/hiteshj/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_19.avd/cache.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '64m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '480'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'none'
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library: dlopen(lib64OpenglRender.dylib, 1): image not found
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.checkjni=1 ndns=1
emulator:     trying to find: /Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools/bios.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools/lib/pc-bios/bios.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools/vgabios-cirrus.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools/lib/pc-bios/vgabios-cirrus.bin

emulator: autoconfig: -scale 0.27817
emulator: Forcing ro.adb.qemud to "0".
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: sent '0012host:emulator:5555' to ADB server
emulator: ping program: /Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ddms
emulator: ping command: /Users/hiteshj/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ddms ping emulator standalone "" "" ""
```

There is one more question I posted, but no help yet.
[question link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580987/panic-missing-emulator-engine-program-for-x86-cpus)

**From last 5 days, I was on the same step. Please help me to overcome from this problem.**

Comment: Check out your antivirus didn't put the emulator executable in quarantine. and see this link may be it can help you.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37826

Comment: the answer is available [here][1] similar question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031903/how-to-fix-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode

Answer (score 7):

As I can see your Android Studio is missing for 'x86' engines for your emulator.
Please check these 2 points:

1. Verify that you have that system image installed. Open your SDK Manager and navigate to Android 4.4.2 folder. Install everything to be sure:

   [image]
2. If it doesn't help, you also can try to change system image for your emulator. Create a new virtual device and this time choose anything except 'x86' if it still not working:

   [image]

Hope it will help you!

Comment: When I try to create new AVD, then it shows "failed to load" error. 
Please help.

Comment: So you can create it, but when try to load it crashes?

Comment: yes, exactly. This happens everytime. I am not able to debug it.

Comment: Which system images have you tried before? x86, what else? Check everything. And what do the logs say now?

Comment: From where, I can see the log ? 
I tried "armeabi-v7a", "mips".

Comment: You showed some logs above. Did they change after changing system image? What do they say to "armeabi"? And what if you try to run your first app on real device? :)

Comment: At the time of creating a new AVD, it shows "Failed to load". Thats why I am not able to check logs.

Comment: And what about trying to change device? Found this: "I've noticed that the crash happens every time I start an AVD that is using the device profile of the "Nexus S". If i use the "Galaxy Nexus" or other device profile, it works fine."

Comment: I didn't able to solve this issue. For a time being, I installed Genymotion. That  seems better than Android Studio's Emulator.
Can we start conversation to resolve my main issue, i.e., to start emulator ?

Comment: Sure! Are there any problems in using Genymotion emulator?

Answer (score 3):

Stop the emulator --> Open ADV Manager -->Edit the Virtual device --> Click Show Advanced Settings --> Set the Ram size 512mb --> Start the emulator