# Android studio virtual device error about the android_SDK_ROOT

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to use the android stdio to develop some app, BUT when I try to open the virtual device, it has some problem.

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not startemulator: 
ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-qemu" is in the same location as your system image.
emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined
```

I already found some solutions about this error, ie. the intel x86 haxm, SDK version, install the jave JDK8... but it's not work yet....What happen about this problem??

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem when I tried to run without any x86 image. You can see here when running the SDK Manager:

[image: SDK Manager]

It worked after the installation of the missing x86 image.

Disclosure: I got this image from another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646766/android-studio-stuck-starting-the-emulator).

Answer (score 1):

you have to download a system image first.