# PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU. [Ionic Cordova run android]

Tags: android, angular, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework

I am using ionic cordova to make a mobile app. I recently just got a new laptop and when I try to run 'ionic cordova run android --prod', I get this error:

> 'PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.'

It was working perfectly on my previous computer, though unfortunately it can't handle the payload of development due to it's low specs.

[image: Error Message pic here]

What can I do about this?

Comment: please post the actual error message, if you can.
pictures don't help much.

Comment: see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51627009/8034839

Comment: also, possible here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51897046/mac-and-panic-missing-emulator-engine-program-for-arm-cpu/52161215#52161215

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tried and verified on your machine add below this under system variables  Path, to solve this problem

```
C:/users/$Whome/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
C:/users/$Whome/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/tools
C:/users/$Whome/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/emulator
```

Comment: ------> **sdk**