# PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU. windows 10

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I have this cordova app and tried to run

```
cordova platform add android
cordova emualate android
```

but it give me below error from the console

[image]

and when I check from the android studio, everything seems installed

[image]

below is my android studio info

[image]

and I my environment variables

[image]

and I can confirm from the folder location that those path I put existed, any help, ideas please?

Answer (score 50):

Check this answer: [PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51627009/8034839) and [Mac and "PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'arm' CPU."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51897046/mac-and-panic-missing-emulator-engine-program-for-arm-cpu/52161215#52161215)

For newer version of Android SDK, the emulator path should be `/<xxx>/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator`, make this path is the first path to be searched in our environment variable.

i.e. add this path to your environment variable `PATH` **BEFORE** `/<xxx>/Android/sdk/tools/emulator`

Or try to remove `/<xxx>/Android/sdk/tools/emulator` from your `PATH` variable.

Comment: This worked for me. The final solution looked like this: export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH

Answer (score 14):

Use x86_64 system images for emulator on Windows 10:

[image: Open "x86 Images" tab and download some of x86_64]

Comment: Defeats the purpose of the emulator is used to test 32 bit native code...

Comment: x86 doesn't start at all

Comment: It worked for me to use x86_64 instead of x86. I had to delete all others devices to be sure this one is taken into account

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a mac make sure to put this in terminal:

```
./emulator -avd "Pixel_3_API_28"
```

Emulator program is in ~[user]/Library/Android/sdk/emulator directory.

Comment: Wow just came back to this and I answered my own question! Make sure you change to the emulator directory in terminal - cd ~/Library/Android/sdk

Answer (score 0):

It might be that Mac OS doesn't run 32bit applications anymore. When you change your simulator to 64 bit (x86_64) it will run fine:

Just install x86_64 version on emulator.
[image: android]