# VSCode Integrated Terminal Doesn't Load .bashrc or .bash_profile

Tags: bash, shell, visual-studio-code, settings

I have the following files to handle shell configuration:

```
#~/.bash_profile
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

and

```
#~/.bashrc
... configure shell
```

If I open VSCode from the command line using `code`, my `.bashrc` is loaded whenever I add a new instance of the integrated shell.

However if I open VSCode via its icon, only my `.profile` is loaded.

**How can I ensure my `.bashrc` is loaded instead?**

I've tried various settings for the `terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx` setting without any luck.

Comment: I was having a problem that it was loading bash_profile instead of bashrc. Deleting the bash_profile file fixed it.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Simply add shell arguments to the VsCode `settings.json` file.

Paths to the `settings.json` file are as follows:

```
Windows: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`

Linux:   $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json

Mac:     $HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/settings.json
```

Add one of the following:

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-l"],

"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": ["-l"],

"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": ["-l"],
```

This will launch your shell of choice with [the `-l` (aka `--login`) argument](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html). This will thus execute any user profile that is setup.

> Make this shell act as if it had been directly invoked by login... When the shell is not interactive, the login shell startup files will be executed.

Comment: These brackets around `["-l"]` are missing when you use the command palette to access this file and insert this setting.  When I added the brackets it worked for me, now osx zsh shell is loading my usual environment.

Comment: To get this to also start in the workspace directory I added this to the end of my `~/.bash_profile`
: 
`[[ -n "${VSCODE_IPC_HOOK_CLI}" ]] && cd "${OLDPWD}" `

Comment: VSCode has deprecated `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx"` in favor of using profiles. I recommend visitors take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 58):

VSCode has deprecated `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx"` in favor of using profiles ([passing the `-l` (aka `--login`) argument to `"args"`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html)). This does the trick for bash in osx. Omit the first line if you don't want bash to be your default profile:

```
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "bash",
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
    "bash": {
      "path": "bash",
      "args": ["-l"]
    }
  }
```

Similar approach for Windows:

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Git Bash": {
      "path": [ "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe" ],
      # --login is same as -l
      "args": [ "--login" ]
    }
}
```

Comment: For other people reference, it works well for me without having to change any terminal related options in Preference -> Settings in the GUI.

My VS Code version `1.74.2`.

Comment: Thanks! This did not quite work for me, I am getting a login shell, but it is batch (`ENVIRONMENT=BATCH`). I still need to figure out how to get `ENVIRONMENT=INTERACTIVE` by default.

Answer (score 29):

Another possible solution that just worked for me. The settings.json file (whcih you can access in File > Preferences > Settings > Features > terminal > Integrated > Automation Shell: Linux) had a parameter

```
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false
```

set to false by default. Changing it to true fixed the problem in my case.

Comment: Gosh, I was searching forever to find this. Thank you!

Comment: This also gave me the needed hint. Actually it seems that now the default of `terminal.integrated.inheritEnv` is `true`, see https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_57#_improved-launching-with-clean-environment

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem with the Intellij Idea terminal on a Mac, the solution is the same for both. In settings change the path to the integrated terminal to "/bin/bash". Hope that helps.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I was having this issue too. But in my case I was on windows with Visual Studio code opening a remote dev env inside my CentOS WSL.

So fixing the configuration of this use case was a bit different.
In the IDE open settings. Then at the top select "Remote [WSL: XXX]"

[image]

The scroll down to Integrated -> Profiles: Linux
And click edit in settings.json
[image]

Then I added the following to the file:

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash",
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
    "bash": {
      "path": "bash",
      "args": ["-l"]
    }
  }
```

Save the settings file and the next terminal you open will respect your ~/.bash_profile.
NOTE: my ~/.bash_profile had the same lines that someone else recommended adding to load the bashrc file in it already.

Comment: Also incase it is usefult for people. The path of the settings file on the WSL file system is: ```/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json```

Comment: For first time WSL terminal is opened, this setting ignored. The deprecated setting worked through `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": ["-l"]` Credit: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6096#issuecomment-1506941761

Answer (score 8):

You could also try the following:

1 Create a file named /usr/local/bin/bash-login and add :

```
#!/bin/bash
bash -l
```

2 Run:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/bash-login
```

to make it executable.

3 On your VSC user settings add

```
   { "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/usr/local/bin/bash-login" }
```

The solution was described at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7263.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

`"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": ["-l"]` is deprecated.

I personally wanted to use `.bash_profile`, so I made a `.bashrc` with this:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

And then I had to do a *full computer restart* (just restarting VS code didn't work).

Comment: should that first line maybe be `if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then`? It doesn't really make sense to test for the existence of a file from within that same file

Comment: @tel good point, Hard to say, I just know that this worked for me.

Comment: +1 for mentioning full computer restart. Nothing was working for me and then this did. I would love to know why this works when logging out and logging in again doesn't.

Comment: Strangely, this worked for me without rebooting or reloading vscode

Answer (score 2):

Bash will load various DotFiles sequentially:

1. `~/.bash_profile`
2. `~/.bash_login`
3. `~/.profile`

If `~/.bash_profile` been loaded, the second and third one will not be loaded.

If `~/.bash_profile` is not loaded, bash will find second one. If `~/.bash_login` been loaded, the third one will not be loaded.

If `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_login` are both not loaded, Bash will try to load `~/.profile` file.

A fresh Ubuntu installation will only contains `~/.profile` file. So I think it will be better NOT to use the `~/.bash_profile` to avoid issues happening. Just use the `~/.profile` file. Then your VSCode won't need to config anything.

Answer (score 2):

I see a lot of people recommending the `-l` parameter to bash but that didn't work for me. Instead use the `-i` parameter (interactive). This goes in your user settings file. This is for Mac OS. If on a different platform change `osx` to either `linux` or `windows`.

```
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
        "bash": {
          "path": "bash",
          "args": ["-i"]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`bash -l` does not load the ~/.bashrc file, while `bash -i` does. The reason for this is that `bash -l` starts a login shell, while `bash -i` starts an interactive shell.

When bash is started as a login shell, it reads and executes commands from the /etc/profile file, followed by the first one of the following files that exists and is readable: ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile. However, when bash is started as an interactive shell, it reads and executes commands from the ~/.bashrc file.

Therefore, when you start a login shell with `bash -l`, it does not read the ~/.bashrc file. However, when you start an interactive shell with `bash -i`, it reads and executes commands from the ~/.bashrc file.