# VScode terminal doesn't seem to load .bashrc or .bash_profile on windows

Tags: bash, settings, git-bash, visual-studio-code

If I start a new integrated terminal in VScode it does not seem to load my .bashrc file. Once the terminal is open I can source ~/.bashrc and the custom settings then appear. My problem seems to be a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51820921/vscode-integrated-terminal-doesnt-load-bashrc-or-bash-profile), however for windows instead of osx.

Is it possible to have vscode automatically source my .bashrc or .bash_profile when it starts a new instance of the integrated terminal?

So far i have tried the following:

I have pointed the terminal to git bash by setting `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"`

I have tried pass a shell argument in the settings, using `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-l"]` however it is not clear in the documentation if this applies to windows or just linux.

Comment: Can you please word your question a little better so we can understand it more? Thanks!

Comment: I have just edited the post. Hopefully it is clear now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to my settings.json fixed this issue for me.

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "-l"
  ]
```

Edit: Derp I am bad at reading. It might work for you if you move your .bashrc content into a .bash_profile file.