# How to get Visual Studio Code to default to my conda installed Python on OSX?

Tags: python, bash, visual-studio, terminal, editor

I tried following the instructions here:
[VSCode Integrated Terminal Doesn't Load .bashrc or .bash_profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51820921/vscode-integrated-terminal-doesnt-load-bashrc-or-bash-profile)

From within `Visual Studio Code`:

```
(base) jespinozlt2-osx:~ jespinoz$ ~/anaconda3/bin/python --version
Python 3.7.3
(base) jespinozlt2-osx:~ jespinoz$ which python
/usr/bin/python
(base) jespinozlt2-osx:~ jespinoz$ source ~/.bash_profile
(base) jespinozlt2-osx:~ jespinoz$ which python
/usr/bin/python
(base) jespinozlt2-osx:~ jespinoz$ which conda
/Users/jespinoz/anaconda3/bin/conda
```

I simply just want it to do the following:

1. Run `source ~/.bash_profile` at start up
2. Not use `/usr/bin/python` at all just like my normal terminal usage

My current settings file:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/Users/jespinoz/anaconda3/bin/python",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "FlatUI Immersed",
    "terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app",
    "terminal.integrated.automationShell.osx": "",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/usr/local/bin/bash-login",

}
```

The contents of `bash-login`:

```
(base) jespinozlt2-osx:~ jespinoz$ cat /usr/local/bin/bash-login
#!/bin/bash
bash -l
```

~/.bash_profile

```
# added by Anaconda3 installer

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/jespinoz/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/jespinoz/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/jespinoz/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/jespinoz/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Comment: You can put `PATH=~/anaconda3/bin/python:$PATH` in your `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: I should have added my bash_profile.   It's already in there which is whyt his is so surprising to me.

Comment: It's in the `else` section, so it's not in effect. You can check by `echo $PATH`

Comment: It's the default in my path when I use the terminal or iTerm but not Visual Studio Code `(base) jespinozlt2-osx:~ jespinoz$ which python
/Users/jespinoz/anaconda3/bin/python`