# Android Emulator launches from Android Studio but not Command Line

Tags: android, android-emulator, avd-manager

I have an odd issue with my Android emulator. Trying to start the emulator from the Command Line results in

```sh
me@machine$ /path/to/android/sdk/tools/emulator @Emu_Name
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.
```

However, when I start the emulator from Android Studio, it works.  Also, I can start *other* Android emulators from the command line, it's just this one specific AVD that is broken.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio is launching the emulator from the directory & file:

`/path/to/android/sdk/emulator/emulator`

(see here https://www.stkent.com/2017/08/10/update-your-path-for-the-new-android-emulator-location.html)

That is the difference.

Running the command:

`me@machine$ /path/to/android/sdk/eumaltor/emulator @Emu_Name`

Should resolve your problem.

Context:

- [Android Emulator Error Message: "PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPUS."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483370/android-emulator-error-message-panic-missing-emulator-engine-program-for-x86/58778882#58778882)
- https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator.html#25-3

Comment: @ellman121 If you found this helpful pls remember to upvote or mark it as answered https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers