# Issues with Android Emulator on OSX - Missing emulator engine program

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

I just updated my Android Studio to 3.5.3 and installed Gradle 4.10.3 for my Ionic project.

I added this to my PATH variable:

```
# Add the Android SDK Path
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
# emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
# avdmanager, sdkmanager
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools
# adb, logcat
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
```

And if I run `${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/emulator/emulator -version` I see this: `Android emulator version 29.3.4.0 (build_id 6110076) (CL:N/A)`

I have one avd installed on my machine and I get it to run by running either of these commands:

```
${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/tools/emulator -avd Pixel_2_XL_API_27
${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_2_XL_API_27
```

It appears that Android gave some priority to the `emulator` binary recently. However, when I run `which emulator` from the CLI, it returns:

```
/Users/[username]/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator
```

When it should be returning:

```
/Users/[username]/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator
```

I am not sure what I have done incorrectly in my config, but I am unable to run an Android emulator from my Ionic project, as I am always greeted with this error:

```
PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.
```

Any thoughts on what I should look at some that I can ensure that I am able to run the emulator from my project?

**EDITS**

I think this may have something to do with my `$PATH` variable. When I `echo $PATH`, this is what is returned:

`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/[username]/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/[username]/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Users/[username]/Library/Android/sdk/emulator:/Users/[username]/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/[username]/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.10.3/bin`

However, this is my entire `$HOME/.bash_profile` :

```
# Create a JAVA_HOME variable, determined dynamically
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
# Add that to the global PATH variable
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
# Add the Android SDK Path
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
# emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
# avdmanager, sdkmanager
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin
# adb, logcat
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
#Set GRADLE_HOME
export GRADLE_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.10.3
export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
```

Where would the **/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/[username]/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/[username]/Library/Android/sdk/tools** in the `$PATH` variable be coming from?

Comment: I have checked out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483370/android-emulator-error-message-panic-missing-emulator-engine-program-for-x86) and it did not resolve my issues. It is still trying to use my `/tools/emulator` vs `/emulator/emulator` to launch my emulators.

Comment: Found the problem. For some reason I had some paths defined in my `/etc/paths`. After I deleted the Android paths from that file, we are back in business.