# How to install Android Studio and SDK with CLI support for Linux and/or Mac OS X?

Tags: android, linux, macos, android-studio, command-line-interface

Instead of install both Android Studio and Android SDK at the **user home directory** (as suggested by the IDE), what would be the proper way of installing them for **two or more users in the same machine**?

The problem arose due system administrators necessity of:

1. Installing the development tools for several users at a single computer.
2. Installing the files at one machine an easily copy the same setup at several machines.
3. Removing users without loosing development tools.
4. Cleaner distro upgrades.
5. Distro migrations (move from Ubuntu to Cento OS or Arch Linux for example).

Answer (score 1):

### TL; DR

**Mac OS X** already installs AS at `/Applications` folder by default.

**Linux** users should install the IDE at `/opt/android-studio` and create a symlink from `bin/studio.sh` to `/usr/local/bin/studio` (see the details section of how to create app launcher icon).

During the IDE install process, change the SDK location to `/opt/google/android`, allowing all users to have access to it. Don't forget to **add write permissions to admin users**, otherwise any AS and SDK updates will required `sudo` permission.

Once finished, the quick-dirty approach is adding this to `/etc/profile`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# WARNING
# Directly modify /etc/profile is not recommended.
# Please read the cleaner approach at the following details section.

export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/google/android
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=${ANDROID_HOME}/ndk-bundle

# PATH exports were split ONLY due THIS post readability
export PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator:${PATH}
export PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${PATH}
export PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${PATH}
```

then logout and login from OS in order to the modifications take effect.

## Details

Even though is possible achieve the result using package managers (`apt`, `brew`, `pacman`, `sdkmanager`, `yum`,`snap`, etc), they rely on third-party package repositories that usually are not part of the official distro repositories.

Thus this solutions is more a matter of personal taste than an absolute truth.

One my read this post as an [old-school way of configuring sysadmin tools](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/fhs.html), allowing you configure other stuff like [Node.js](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594656/how-to-install-the-latest-versions-of-nodejs-and-npm/850993#850993), [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk), [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli), etc.

That being said, suppose your username at Linux/OS X is `stark` and that there are more than one user registered at your workstation (`potts` and `widow` for example), but only you and `widow` are administrators.

### 1. Linux & Unix

We wish to create an SDK folder where multiple users may access both IDE and CLI tools without sharing the content of my personal folder (i.e. `/home/stark` or `/Users/widow`)

The solution is to install the SDK at `/opt`, [since they are not part the distribution and the binaries downloaded from a third-party](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11544/what-is-the-difference-between-opt-and-usr-local) (i.e. not compiled by us through `Makefile`).

Since only `root` has permission to modify `/opt`, but it is not a good idea to use `sudo` every time you need to update the SDK, an old-school approach would be create a folder where only an specific group has write privileges:

```sh
sudo mkdir /opt/google/android
sudo chmod g+w /opt/google/android

# At Mac OS, use admin contrary to adm
usermod -a -G adm stark
usermod -a -G adm widow
```

I have used `/opt/google/android` because the same approach may be used for other Google SDK tools (Firebase or [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/sdk) for example), keeping all Google CLI tools at the same place.

```
/opt/
├── anaconda
├── gradle
├── jetbrains
│   ├── pycharm
│   ├── studio
│   └── webstorm
├── node
├── google
│   ├── android
│   ├── chrome
│   └── cloud
└── sonarqube
```

With the intention of exporting the CLI commands to all users, the best approach is configure the `PATH` variable at the highest `profile` level. For the purpose of the house clean and organized, instead of adding it directly to `/etc/profile`, let's create `/etc/profile.d/android.sh` as follows:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/google/android
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=${ANDROID_HOME}/ndk-bundle

# Emulator must come before tools directory
# See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483370
export PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator:${PATH}
export PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${PATH}
export PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${PATH}
```

By default, Ubuntu already iterates over `/etc/profile.d`, exporting all shell defined at the `*.sh` files, consequently we may keep the configurations semantically organized:

```
/etc/profile.d/
├── anaconda.sh
├── android.sh
├── gcloud.sh
├── gradle.sh
├── node.sh
└── sonarqube.sh
```

Mac OS X does not export by default files at `/etc/profile.d`, requiring this code at `/etc/profile`:

```sh
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

Unlike `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc`, that are loaded every time a new terminal is opened, `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` [are loaded once you login into your system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment). Thus it is required re-login into your window manager (or OS X) before proceed to the IDE install process.

Keeping the SDK installed at `/opt` is useful because:

- Allows you to remove your IDE without loosing the bunch of platform files already downloaded
- If you keep separated partitions (like for `/home`), you may do the same for `/opt` and `/usr/local`.
- System administrators can easily [copy the development tools at several machines using `rsync`](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/rsync-command-examples/) without have to worry with custom references at `PATH` for each `/home` user.

### 2. Install Android Studio

At some point during the IDE install process, it will be requested the location of (an existent) SDK. Change it to `/opt/google/android` rather than the default at your home directory.

[image: Android Studio IDE]

#### 2.1. Linux

Following the same idea, [download and install Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio) at `/opt`:

```sh
mkdir /opt/jetbrains/

# At Mac OS, use admin contrary to adm
usermod -a -G adm stark
usermod -a -G adm widow

# Unpack and move
sudo tar -xvzf ~/Downloads/android-studio-ide-linux.tar.gz -C /opt/jetbrains/
sudo mv /opt/jetbrains/android-studio /opt/jetbrains/studio
sudo chgrp adm /opt/jetbrains/studio

# Allow calling Android Studio from command line
sudo ln -s /opt/jetbrains/studio/bin/studio.sh /usr/local/bin/studio
```

For invoking AS from launchers like Gnome Shell, Unity HUD, etc., create an app launcher at `/usr/share/applications/jetbrains-studio.desktop` as follows:

```sh
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Android Studio
Icon=/opt/jetbrains/studio/bin/studio.png
Exec="/opt/jetbrains/studio/bin/studio.sh" %f
Comment=The Drive to Develop
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-studio
```

For users whom keep simultaneously several AS versions, you may keep separated folders such as:

```sh
# Stable release
/opt/jetbrains/studio/stable

# Unstable release
/opt/jetbrains/studio/canary
```

#### 2.2 Mac OS X

Apple users will should install the IDE simply unpacking the `*.dmg` file at `Applications` folder.