# How to fix "Unable to locate adb" error in AVD Manager?

Tags: android-studio, adb, avd-manager, platform-tools

I can not find any solution for this error when starting virtual device.
There are some similar topics here, I know, but it seems that none of them solves my issue.

I tried:

- uninstall/install Android SDK Platform Tools in SDK Manager
- add Platform Tools path to system PATH variable (windows)
- set ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT
- download Platform Tools from https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools and install it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me extending my path helped.

```
%ANDROID_SDK%\emulator
%ANDROID_SDK%\platform-tools
%ANDROID_SDK%\tools
%ANDROID_SDK%\tools\bin
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54030970/16364154

Answer (score -1):

I just did this today
1>First of all disable fast restart from [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup)
2>Then enable VT-x from [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/)
3>Third go to your antivirus. If AVG, open the menu options and click quarantine.Else see where to find quaratine chestbox for your antivirus  And then there should be something whose file name will be adb.exe. Yes, even if it it shows in the platform tools, there will be a file with file location Idead or something like that and restore it
4>Then go to your android studio and go to file in the top left corner. Click invalidate/caches and then Invalidate and Restart. Then try.
5> Also go to the sdk manager and update everything that isn't updated.
6>Should work\

If this does not work, just comment it and I will find a new way