# Android Emulator issues on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: android, emulation

I'm having a bit of an issue with the emulator launching from Eclipse. I have everything set up to the letter as far as I can tell and I'm just following the Hello, World example and when I try and run it after setting up the emulator I get this:

[2011-08-18 17:43:16 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: Files\Android\android-sdk\tools/emulator-arm.exe.
[2011-08-18 17:43:16 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2011-08-18 17:43:16 - Emulator] please use -help for more information

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting the Android emulator in SDK tools, revision 12](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603194/starting-the-android-emulator-in-sdk-tools-revision-12)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use spaces in sdk path.If your sdk contains path like program files/sdk-windsows then it will prompt error.Place in a directory where no spaces exists

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it!
Does Eclipse/Android do any other stupid things I should be aware of?

Comment: Yes,some other things happens.But it depends.Sometimes emulator can't start if firewall is turned on.